# How To Set Title In Another Activity Based on The Text of The Selected Spinner Option On Clicking A Button In The Main Activity

Tags: java, android, button, android-intent, spinner

I set out to create a project of an Android app consisting of 3 activities.

The first activity has a layout with 3 elements, 2 spinners and a button.

I set out with an intention to make them work in the following manner:

MainActivity.java:
 1. Let's just say that I wanted the first spinner to load a set of categories on app startup. e.g., Income, Expenditure.
 2. After I select a category from the first spinner, the second spinner will load up its respective sub-categories in the second spinner. e.g., If I choose Income in the first spinner, the second spinner with load up Commission, Salary, Bonus, etc. and if Expenditure is chosen, Monthly Expenditure, Conveyance, Bills, etc are loaded in the second spinner.
 3. Now, on the basis of which sub-category I chose, when I click the button, it will open a new activity and set the title of the action bar for that particular category and sub-category. e.g., If I chose Income and Salary, the next activity will show Income, Salary as title after I click the button in the main activity.

I have created a class named Utils.java to store the set of category and sub-category names as string arrays.

```
public class Utils{

    public static String[] mainCategoryList =
    {
        "Choose One",
        "Income",
        "Expenditure"
    };

    //
    public static String[] chooseOne_list=
    {
        "Choose One"
    };

    public static String[] income_subCategoryList =
    {
        "Bonus",
        "Commision",
        "Salary"                 
    };

    public static String[] expenditure_subCategoryList=
    {
         "Bills",
         "Conveyance",
         "Monthly Expenditure"
    };

    public static String[] income=
    {
        "Income, Bonus",
        "Income, Commission",
        "Income, Salary"
    };

    public static String[] expenditure=
    {
        "Expenditure, Bills",
        "Expenditure, Conveyance",
        "Expenditure, Monthly Expenditure"
    };
}
```

The coding I have done for MainActivity.java is given below,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner spinner1_mainCategory, spinner2_subCategory;
Button buttonChoose;
String spinner1Item, spinner2Item;
Intent intent;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Spinner element
    spinner1_mainCategory = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1_mainCategory);
    spinner2_subCategory = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2_subCategory);

    //Button element
    buttonChoose = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);

    //To keep onCreate() clean of multiple adapter setting
    adapterMethod(spinner1_mainCategory,mainCategoryList);

    // Spinner click listener
    spinner1_mainCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            //String.valueOf(array_name.getSelectedItem()) captures the value of the selected option of a specific string array onClick event
            spinner1Item = String.valueOf(spinner1_mainCategory.getSelectedItem());


            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    adapterMethod(spinner2_subCategory,chooseOne_list);
                    spinner2_subCategory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //Button click listener
                    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            if (spinner1Item.contentEquals(Utils.mainCategoryList[0])){
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Choose a Category First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,0,0);
                                toast.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case 1:
                    adapterMethod(spinner2_subCategory,income_subCategoryList);
                    spinner2_subCategory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    adapterMethod(spinner2_subCategory,expenditure_subCategoryList);
                    spinner2_subCategory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });


    spinner2_subCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long id) {
            spinner2Item = String.valueOf(spinner2_subCategory.getSelectedItem());

            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    //Income Category, Bonus Sub-category
                    if (spinner2Item.contentEquals(Utils.mainCategoryList[1]) && spinner2Item.contentEquals(income_subCategoryList[0])){
                        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                changeTitleInNextActivity(Utils.income[0]);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    //Expenditure Category, Bills Sub-category
                    if (spinner2Item.contentEquals(Utils.mainCategoryList[2]) && spinner2Item.contentEquals(expenditure_subCategoryList[0])){
                        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                changeTitleInNextActivity(Utils.expenditure[0]);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    break;
                case 1:
                    //Income Category, Commission Sub-category
                    if (spinner2Item.contentEquals(Utils.mainCategoryList[1]) && spinner2Item.contentEquals(income_subCategoryList[1])){
                        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                changeTitleInNextActivity(Utils.income[1]);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    //Expenditure Category, Conveyance Sub-category
                    if (spinner2Item.contentEquals(Utils.mainCategoryList[2]) && spinner2Item.contentEquals(expenditure_subCategoryList[1])){
                    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            changeTitleInNextActivity(Utils.expenditure[1]);
                        }
                    });
                }

                break;
                case 2:
                    //Income Category, Salary Sub-category
                    if (spinner2Item.contentEquals(Utils.mainCategoryList[1]) && spinner2Item.contentEquals(income_subCategoryList[2])){
                        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                changeTitleInNextActivity(Utils.income[2]);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    //Expenditure Category, Monthly Expenditure Sub-category
                    if (spinner2Item.contentEquals(Utils.mainCategoryList[2]) && spinner2Item.contentEquals(expenditure_subCategoryList[2])){
                        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                changeTitleInNextActivity(Utils.expenditure[2]);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}

public void adapterMethod(View v, String[] list){
    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // attaching adapter to spinner for district
    if (v.getId()==R.id.spinner1_mainCategory){
        spinner1_mainCategory.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner1_mainCategory.setSelection(0, false);
    }
    if (v.getId()==R.id.spinner2_subCategory){
        spinner2_subCategory.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner2_subCategory.setSelection(0, false);
    }
}

public void changeTitleInNextActivity(String title){

    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Title", title);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String title = intent.getStringExtra("Title");
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

}

I don't understand why, but I can't get the coding to work for me the way I wanted it to. Selection from the first and second spinner works perfectly, but its the button that I can't get to work to set the title in the next activity no matter how many approaches I try.

Tell me, guys, what did I do wrong? How to better code to avoid this kind of pitfall.

Can't make the Button "Choose":

1. to go to the SecondActivity

Comment: Post your ButtonsActivity class

Comment: public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

Comment: public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
 }
}

Comment: @BodhisatwaChakraborty Post your class inside your post, not in the comments.

Comment: Sorry about that, new to stackoverflow, was just getting familiar with the whole site^__^

Now, will you please look into the coding and let me know what did I do wrong? :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second activity,
get your passed string

```
String title=getIntent().getStringExtra("Title");
```

Then set your title

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out that I forgot to add the piece of coding to set Title in action bar itself for the Second Activity, I have rectified that aspect. But alas! but no, it's not the reason why I am having problems implementing my code. 

Please look into the coding again and show me where I did wrong

Comment: Could you test the value of title in the changeTitleInNextActivity method,and does an actionbar with no name show or not?

Comment: The only thing I think happening is the if else statement args are not quite working properly in the spinner2's onItemSelectedListener